# CancellationToken.WaitHandle not waiting long enough

Tags: .net

I am seeing a very unexpected behavior with WaitHandle.  I use it on a CancellationToken that I have called CancelAfter on.  I tell it to cancel after 2 seconds, but it occasionally quits in less time (e.g. 00:00:01.9976838).  I could understand if threads were busy and it took a little longer, but I cannot understand why it would ever take less time than specified.  Below is a unit test I have that works 9 out of 10 times, but ever once in a while, the Assert fails, because WaitHandle finished too fast.  Can anyone help me understand why this would ever finish too quickly?

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Uses a WaitHandle to stop a Task after a specified time
    /// </summary>
    [Fact]
    public void TestTokenWaitHandle()
    {
        using (var cts = new CancellationTokenSource())
        {
            // test cancelling method

            var sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
            var cancelAfter = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2);
            cts.CancelAfter(cancelAfter);
            var t = Task.Run(() =>
            {
                var success = cts.Token.WaitHandle.WaitOne(cancelAfter + TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2));
                cts.Token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
            });

            try
            {
                t.Wait(cts.Token);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                // expect WaitHandle to throw OperationCanceledException
            }

            sw.Stop();

            AssertES.True(sw.Elapsed >= cancelAfter, $"Should have taken full time to run.  Elapsed: {sw.Elapsed.ToString()} cancelAfter: {cancelAfter.ToString()}");
            var expectedUnder = cancelAfter + TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1);
            AssertES.True(sw.Elapsed < expectedUnder, $"Should have completed soon after cancellation.  Elapsed: {sw.Elapsed.ToString()} expectedUnder: {expectedUnder.ToString()}");
        }
    }
```

Comment: What happens if you move `var sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();` after the line `cts.CancelAfter(cancelAfter);`

Comment: @Charlieface, the issue is so random that I don't know how to test that, but to me it seems like that would just exacerbate the issue, since I would be starting the timer even later than I do now, as the earlier I start sw, the larger sw.Elapsed should be, thus increasing my odds of the test passing.

Comment: Maybe you're right. Some more things that come to mind: Depending on your machine, the Windows timer mechanism may not be 100% accurate. The code you have is very strange: you are waiting on an auto-cancelling token inside the task, but adding a double delay which in theory should never be hit anyway, then you are waiting on the task but passing the token *again*, which means you don't actually wait for the task as the cancellation happens first (this is only reason you need the `catch` as it can't catch the exception from inside the task, to catch that exception you would need `await`).

Comment: I must say I cannot replicate your problem with your exact code no matter how many times I run it which makes me think that it is something to do with your machine or operating system. What is the result of `Stopwatch.IsHighResolution`?

Comment: Actually I did get it once after running it in a loop 100 times. I think it's probably a rounding artifact